# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'candyMachineAddress')

Tags: typescript, solana, nft

I want to set a date to my candy_machine for my NFT's
I did this command

```
 ts-node js/packages/cli/src/candy-machine-cli.ts update_candy_machine --keypair ~/.config/solana/mainnet-beta.json --date '3 Oct 2021 00:00:00 UTC'
```

But i get this error:

```
.option('-b, --batchSize <number>', 'Batch size - defaults to 1000')
                      ^
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'candyMachineAddress')
    at C:\Users\Gebruiker\OneDrive\Documenten\nft-projects\weird-eggs-metaplex\metaplex\js\packages\cli\src\candy-machine-cli.ts:773:53
    at step (C:\Users\Gebruiker\OneDrive\Documenten\nft-projects\weird-eggs-metaplex\metaplex\js\packages\cli\src\candy-machine-cli.ts:64:23)
    at Object.next (C:\Users\Gebruiker\OneDrive\Documenten\nft-projects\weird-eggs-metaplex\metaplex\js\packages\cli\src\candy-machine-cli.ts:45:53)
    at fulfilled (C:\Users\Gebruiker\OneDrive\Documenten\nft-projects\weird-eggs-metaplex\metaplex\js\packages\cli\src\candy-machine-cli.ts:36:58)
```